# Does the DLR or better Iron Python run in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

Does the DLR or even better Iron Python run in Silverlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use IronPython for Silverlight.  Here are [some examples](http://www.codeplex.com/sdlsdk).

Answer (score 3):

Please look at http://ironpython.codeplex.com for the latest Silverlight integration; http://sdlsdk.codeplex.com is closed for business.

Comment: FYI, the `Iron Pyton in the Browser` sample points to an invalid xap url - http://ironpython.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SilverlightInteractiveSession

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Silverlight.net just broke that link.